# Add dynamic styling to hide row in dynamic html table

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, js

I am generating HTML table rows with data dynamically based on salesforce data from apex. Below is the structure.

```
    <template for:each={Details} for:item="Detail">
      <tr data-id={Detail.pbId} key={Detail.pbId}>
        <td>
        <input name={Detail.pbId} value={Detail.pbOrder} size="1"></input>
        </td>
        <td>
        <lightning-button-icon id={Detail.pbId} icon-name="utility:delete" variant="bare" onclick={handleRemove}></lightning-button-icon>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>

    handleRemove(event){
        var id = event.target.id;
        var rowId = event.target.closest("tr").id;
        alert(rowId +' '+ id);
        // this.template.querySelectorAll(id).style="display:none";
        // this.template.querySelectorAll(id).classList.add('hide');
        // this.template.querySelector('.id').style="color:red";
        // this.template.querySelectorAll('[id="' +id+ '"]').classList.add('hide');
        // this.template.querySelectorAll('[id="' +id+ '"]').className = 'hide';
        const theDiv = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="' +id+ '"]');
        theDiv.className = 'hide';
}

.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

I want to delete the row from the dom when delete button is clicked. In the JS you can see I have tried lot of things but none of them worked. Can anyone guide me towards the right way to hide in LWC JS
Tried below link as well:
[Use template.querySelector with variable for selector?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318793/use-template-queryselector-with-variable-for-selector)

Previously in Aura I have dome similar functionality using below line but it is not working in LWC. Or maybe I am doing something wrong.

```
document.getElementById(recordId).style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Do you want to *delete* the element, or merely *hide* it?

Comment: if I have to delete from the shadow dom or dom then what method should i use?

Comment: I was able to use .remove() to remove from dom as well.

Comment: you can add `isHidden` property to you `Details` items in JS and then when you iterate use <template if:false={Detail.isHidden}>. But CSS classes can also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `classList` on your `tr` to add `hidden` class and this should work.

```
handleRemove(event){
        var id = event.target.id;
        const tr = event.target.closest("tr");
        tr.classList.add('hide');
}
```

Comment: Omg thanks it worked. But I am still trying to understand what was I doing wrong? Why didnt it worked with data-id? All the ids and data-id for the row I am settign the same value. Then why?

Comment: because you need to use `classList` and then `add/remove/toggle` methods. When you were using `classList` in comented code you used incorrect selector `[id="' +id+ '"]` instead of `[data-id="' +id+ '"]`